# During Maintenance in MSSQL SERVER i am getting the error: the step failed

Tags: sql-server, maintenance

In MSSQL Server, every Saturday a maintenance plan starts, where it rebuilds some indexes.
During the last month, it always fails after some hours with the message: The step failed.

```
Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.

...PK_dbo.__MigrationHistory] ON [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 90) 
[SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 0)  ITEM 2 FROM 508 [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 0)  ALTER INDEX [PK_dbo.__MigrationHistory] ON [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 90)
[SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 0)  ITEM 3 FROM 508 [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 0)  ALTER INDEX [PK_dbo.ONEINDEX] ON [dbo].[TABLE1] REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 90)
[SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 0)  ITEM 4 FROM 508 [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 0)  ALTER INDEX [PK_dbo.INDEX] ON [dbo].[TABLE2] REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,  
...  The step failed.
```

How can i further investigate the problem? i guess there's a timeout somewhere but need to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did that text you posted come from, exactly?

For maint plans, you have three four of diagnostics information (error messages etc):

1. The report file, if you specified such a file. This contains the commands executed and possible error messages.
2. The email, if you included such.
3. The main plan history tables. There is a GUI for that if you check the history for your maint plan. In Object Explorer, Management Maintenance Plans, select your maintenance plan and "View history".
4. The Agent job history. This is less easy to digest, but can be good to have if any of above doesn't cut it. Agent limits the history for a lob step to 4000 characters and it seems like you posted the Agent job output, and the actual error messages were truncated from the job history tables because of the length of the output.

Here's an example query querying the Agent job history table in the msdb database:

```
SELECT j.name, jh.run_date, jh.run_time, jh.message, *
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory AS jh 
 INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS j ON jh.job_id = j.job_id   
ORDER BY 
 j.name
,jh.run_date DESC
,jh.run_time
,jh.instance_id DESC
```

And here's a sample query for the maintenance plan history tables:

```
SELECT * 
FROM msdb.dbo.sysmaintplan_log AS spl
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysmaintplan_logdetail AS ld ON ld.task_detail_id=spl.task_detail_id
```

What you posted doesn't include error messages, so by that alone we can't help. Check out the other sources I listed above and see if any of them will help.

Note 1: Maintenance plans doesn't have the best reputation. It is pretty common to use something else, like for instance Ola Hallengren's [maintenance solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/).

Note 2: One can argue that you won't gain anything (or much) be blindly defragmenting indexes. [Here's](https://sqlblog.karaszi.com/index-fragmentation-revisited/) a blog post I wrote on the subject.

Comment: i grabbed that message from a query that i found, let me post it here: select j.name
    ,js.step_name
    ,jh.sql_severity
    ,jh.message
    ,jh.run_date
    ,jh.run_time
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS j
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps AS js
   ON js.job_id = j.job_id
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory AS jh
   ON jh.job_id = j.job_id AND jh.step_id = js.step_id
WHERE jh.run_status = 0
AND run_date > '20230301'

Comment: when i dived into SQL Agent Job History, no entries were having the date were it did occur, for example this Sunday 7. The Agent history contain log until 5, Friday. moreover, i have not specified Email, nor i have specified report file. Is this a good idea to enhance the plan in order to grab the error message from the next time it occurs?

Comment: You can still look at history for the maint plan (3 in my answer). But if that doesn't help you, yes add one or two more (1 and/or 2 in my answer).

Comment: Is the GUI under the Agent ? And if so, could you please help me find it?

Comment: If it is the GUI I think Tibor is talking about, in SSMS, in the Object Explorer pane, under SQL Server Agent, find the job in question, right-click, and select Job History.

Comment: The logs that are located there, are only until 5 May, while the Job Boomed on 7th May. i'd like to check the latest

Comment: No, don't look at the Agent history, you have already done that (that is item 4 in my post). And I already mentioned the Agent history is limited to 4000 characters and your error messages is cut off because of that. Right click your maintenance plan (item 3 in my list, under Management), not the Agent job. I have added a bunch of details to my answer. Please re-read.

Comment: @TiborKaraszi thank you Tibor, i'm now investigating and reading the posts you added above!

Comment: After further investigation, using  a monitoring tool i have seen that the error message is:The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached". so as far as i have searched, this message indicates that there are open connections that block actions. is my assumption correct?

Comment: I don't know what "monitoring tool" you refer to, but regardless that error is likely not from your maintenance plans. To the best of my knowledge, they don't use connection pooling, and even if it were, it wouldn't consume all connections in the pool. My prior recommendation stands: Find the error message from your maintenance plan, using any of the 3 remaining sources, of the 4 I listed in my answer.

Comment: Yes, as it seemed the error is not associated with the one we have here. what i got from the number 3 you said was that the job was invoked by schedule 10. Note that the schedule 10 refers to that job so it seems that it invoked itself?

Comment: No any of the three *remaining* sources. We have ruled out job history already. Also, you say you checked number 3, but you refer to output from job, ie number 4. Please read my text more carefully. If you can't get to the relevant error messages, the  we can't help you.

Comment: @TiborKaraszi, doing the number 3, by using the query you sent me: All the records have NULL in error_number and nothing in error_message.

Comment: Ok, if maint plan history tables doesn't help you, then add report file and possible email and see if it happens again.

Comment: Just to update the case, @TiborKaraszi we have received the error of: Could not Continue scan with nolock due to data movement. As i have searched a bit, this means that there's incosistency.

Comment: Probably because you have application s using the NOLOCK hint. Not related to this case, sl better to open a new case for that.

Comment: Yes, i just wanted to update the case, that i found the error. Thank you for your help.